# Rails static assets not caching with CloudFlare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, asset-pipeline, cloudflare

I have a Rails 4.2.10 site on Heroku with CloudFlare activated. However, CloudFlare keeps reporting a MISS on my static assets. CloudFlare has been no help. Any ideas?

Website: https://www.eventingvolunteers.com/

```
Request URL:https://www.eventingvolunteers.com/assets/application-c5697db660693224e57f66260130bdeb07762900fb1b56009477833c84c6c589.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200  (from memory cache)
Remote Address:104.27.157.140:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
cache-control:public, max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status:MISS
cf-ray:3c3d502a79045735-IAD
content-encoding:br
content-type:application/javascript
date:Sun, 26 Nov 2017 13:49:48 GMT
expires:Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:49:48 GMT
last-modified:Sun, 26 Nov 2017 13:47:31 GMT
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:1.1 vegur
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
```

Answer (score 2):

This js file was served from your browser cache, hence CF cache status is MISS

Disable cache in browser an reload, cf-cache-status will be HIT

[image]